# Which Logback Appender to use to send new events to splunk via REST reciever endpoint?

Tags: rest, logback, splunk, appender

Which Logback appender should I use if I want to create new events using the Splunk's REST receivers endpoint if I'm using logback framework. I want to make a custom basic appender for that? Is it socket appender?

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in appender. However following [Which Logback Appender to use to send new events to splunk via REST reciever endpoint?](http://splunk-base.splunk.com/answers/44888) <sup>(which BTW has a surprisingly similar layout to SO)</sup> I found [SplunkJavaLogging](https://github.com/damiendallimore/SplunkJavaLogging) project, specifically the [`SplunkRestAppender`](https://github.com/damiendallimore/SplunkJavaLogging/blob/master/src/com/dtdsoftware/splunk/logging/logback/appender/SplunkRestAppender.java).

Answer (score 1):

That is correct Tomasz , SplunkJavaLogging  has log4j and logback appenders and also a java.util logging handler for anyone still using that framework.

https://github.com/damiendallimore/SplunkJavaLogging

http://dev.splunk.com/view/community-projects/SP-CAAAED7